# Why isn't this simplicial complex locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Something isn't clicking in my understanding of simplicial complexes. I'm looking to prove that a simplicial complex $K$ is locally finite iff $|K|$ is locally compact. The forward direction is easy, it's the converse I'm struggling with. To investigate, I looked at a simplicial complex which wasn't locally finite, to see why it also couldn't be locally compact.

The example I chose was $K$ the union of line segments from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1/n)$ for $n = 1, 2, ...$. Clearly the vertex which invalidates local finiteness is $(0, 0)$, so one would expect this to be the point which has no compact neighbourhood. Every other point seems "well-behaved" enough to possess a compact neighbourhood...

However, I fail to see why $(0, 0)$ would cause trouble. It seems like the closed line segment from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$ (call it $L$) would work fine, no? A set is $U$ open in $|K|$ if and only if it's intersection $U\cap \sigma$ with every face $\sigma$ of $K$ is also open (in $\sigma$). So if we have an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}_\alpha$ of $L$, then $\{U_\alpha\cap L\}_\alpha$ is an open cover of $L$ in $L$, which is compact (in the subspace topology), and hence possesses a finite subcover $\{U_{\alpha_k}\cap L\}_{k=1}^N$, and so $\{U_{\alpha_k}\}_{k=1}^N$ is a finite subcover of $L$ in the topology on $|K|$. Am I wrong?

If I'm not wrong, then which point fails to have a compact neighbourhood and why?

Comment: $L$ is not a neighborhood of $(0,0)$...

Comment: Ah, I've failed to distinguish between a compact set containing $(0, 0)$ and specifically a compact  _neighbourhood_ of $(0, 0)$. Thanks for clarifying!